# How to get PHP working after LEMP with 16.04 installation? I get error 404 even with info.php file

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-code-404

I am getting a 404 error when I try to load any PHP file on my server including info.php. I installed LEMP with 16.04 but it seems hard to find why my php is not working.

My nginx sites-available file looks like this:

```
    server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name website.com www.website.com;

location / {
        root /var/www/website.com/html;
index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;


}

}

server {
listen 443;
ssl on;
# sslcertificate
sslcertificate /etc/nginx/certchain.crt;
# sslcertificatekey
sslcertificate_key /root/website.com.key;

server_name website.com website.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
location / {

root /var/www/website.com/html;
index index.php  index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

}

location ~ .php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found and resolved the issue, I moved `root /var/www/website.com/html;
index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;` to the top just before server name and added some other code which you can see below.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }



    }


    server {
    listen 443;
    ssl on;
            # ssl_certificate
            ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert_chain.crt;
            # ssl_certificate_key
            ssl_certificate_key /root/example.com.key;

             root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

            server_name example.com www.example.com;
            access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
            error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
    location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }



}
```